# Polish specific characters in ejs

Tags: html, node.js, utf-8, ejs

I have set up a node js based server. I need to display specific polish characters in one of my pages. I have tried to add few lines I found in internet but there was no success, I'm still getting "?" instead of getting polish character. For views I use ejs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" >
    <title>KOLEJKA</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon1.png" />
</head>
<body style="background-color: #c2c2d6; overflow: hidden">
<div id = "NazwaPrzychodni">
    Niepubliczny Zakład Medycyny Rodzinnej <br />
    "Modzelewska - Bakun" S.C.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My actual result is "Niepubliczny Zak?ad medycyny rodzinnej" instead of "Niepubliczny Zakład medycyny rodzinnej". (you can find it in div).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>KOLEJKA</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
        <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon1.png" />
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #c2c2d6; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="NazwaPrzychodni">
        Niepubliczny Zakład Medycyny Rodzinnej <br />
        "Modzelewska - Bakun" S.C.
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For me, this code works OK :
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/DKvMsvAwoxMPu36J?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this works for plain html. I'm using ejs, so my source file is not eg. "index.html" but "index.ejs".